# Marketing Cloud System user updating Accounts in Salesforce CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have been facing a unique situation where we are seeing lot of updates from Marketing Cloud user(MC System user) in Salesforce Account object. Our Service and Marketing Cloud are connected by MC Connect.The issue is When MC System user makes an update(multiple times) on Account object,it is configured in our code to make a callout to MDM system. Any update on Account object is followed by a callout to MDM system and we have making a lot of unnecessary callouts to MDM but When we check the Account object history, we don't see any update per se. What could be the potential reasons? Is any tracking update made by Marketing cloud back to Service cloud related to Account object?

Answer (score 1):

From the details sounds like that the Account record was used in some Email send activities and tracking related data is flowing back to Salesforce.
Though, the update won't happen directly to account object but to its contacts, as IER are basically tied to Lead, Contact.